# Phonegap 3.0.0 + Android always wants to use remote environment

Tags: cordova

```
phonegap build ios
```

works correct; it adds iOS to the platforms, but

```
phonegap build android
```

always wants me to sign in:

```
iMAc:myFirstApp2 $ phonegap build android
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the remote environment
[phonegap] PhoneGap/Build Login
[phonegap] Sign up at build.phonegap.com
 [warning] GitHub accounts are unsupported
  [prompt] enter username:    [error] canceled
```

in the documentation for 3.0.0 (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html) it seems as if it's possible to use the local environment as well. I already set the paths correctly:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/haemi/libs/sdk/platform-tools/:/Users/haemi/libs/sdk/tools
```

How do I make sure it's using the local environment rather than a remote environment?

Comment: That seems like a different problem, maybe you should close this question and ask another one.

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this.. I'm also facing the same problem.. When i try local it says install latest api... But it is already up to date..

Answer (score 63):

You can use:

```
phonegap local build android
```

To force it to run using the local environment.

What version of the Android SDK do you have installed? I don't think it works with version 18. I had the same problem and had to install version 17.

Comment: can you give download link for Android SDK version 17

Comment: I installed it through the Android SDK Manager.

Comment: thanks. I installed it using Android SDK Manager too, but it is not obvious in Android tools site.

Comment: I did that once. After that, it is always building locally even with `phonegap build android`. How to switch back to remote build?

Comment: I don't remember it doing it with me. But you can use `phonegap remote build android`.

Comment: I have both 18 and 17 installed. I just installed 17 and it worked.

Answer (score 7):

I overcame the above mentioned situation but my phonegap application doesn't get installed on the emulator though it gives "successfully installed onto device message".
To run the app locally issue following command from the subfolder of the project:

**phonegap local run android**

before running this command make sure you have java_home set and included in path variable, location of ant.bat in the path variable and the location of javac(inside the jdk\bin) in the path variable. With these things i was able to get successfully compiled message.

**EDIT** : though the application isn't automatically installed in the device , the files corresponding to the project ".java" files "res" folder and all the essential files got created inside the project folder

Answer (score 0):

You must install the sdk android first. goto http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html to download the package.
furthermore extract them, and open the "sdk manager" at your path.
install more package of API's as you needs.

i recommend to install gingerbread(2.3) api 10 and ICS(4.0) version.

after finished, goto phonegap "getting started" page http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html .

follow up the instructions. you can install "ant" from ant.apache.org. but in new package of these i rather confused, how to install them. on this progress you may find a trouble to installing "ant" package same as me. but don't worry, I've found the answer.

just follow this instruction on youtube*com/watch?v=bAbBqrTG3q4 . by using my package on drive*google*com/file/d/0B4B3LaTbByxAWlVpQjJhSjd5dVU/edit?usp=sharing .

if you still have an error, you can call me on YM : rifqi_platinum25.

after you have successed install the "ant","java", and "sdk", please try again to build project android.  You should've been able to build it with the local environment. :)

hope its can help you.

note: change [*] with [.] to access the page. i'm sorry for inconvenience because i haven't at least 10 reputation to post with over 2 links. thank's.